# Firebase Swift queryOrderedByChild fired twice

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am coding an iOS chat application where I reload the next 50 messages as a user scrolls up 50. This requires removing the previous observer on the query, and registering a new query with a new limit.

However, **sometimes** (not all the time!) the query is fired twice when I do this change. I realize that this behavior does not happen when I removed `queryOrderedByChild` and just used `queryLimited`.

Here's my code:

```
// Before this function is called I removed the handle at the query

func reobserveChatMessages(limit: UInt, connection: Connection, completed: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ connection: Connection?) -> ()) -> (FIRDatabaseQuery, FIRDatabaseHandle) {

    let uid = getStoredUid() == nil ? "" : getStoredUid()!
    let chatId: String = getChatId(uid1: uid, uid2: connection.uid)
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = REF_MESSAGES.child(chatId)

    // Query with a new limit
    let q: FIRDatabaseQuery = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: limit)

    let handle = q.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        let conn = self.processChatSnapshot(snapshot: snapshot, connection: connection, uid: uid)
        completed(conn != nil, conn)
    })
    return (q, handle)
}
```

Also if it helps, I am using `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true`.

**EDIT: Oddly enough, when I remove persistence this problem goes away. How do I maintain persistence yet still do the above?**